# C++, vector: getting incorrect output containing 0's

Tags: c++, vector, output

Why is the vector 'r' giving the output as follows? Instead, it should not have zero in the list.

Can someone help?

output: `0 0 0 0 0 5 1 2 3 4`

```
vector <int> leftRotation(vector <int> a, int d) {
vector<int> r(a.size());

// int j=0;
for(int i=d; i<a.size(); i++)
    r.push_back(a[i]);

for(int i=0; i<d; i++)
    r.push_back(a[i]);

return r;
}
```

Comment: The core issue at hand is that you are writing C++ based on guessing. That does not work. Learn C++ systematically from a good book and look up stuff in cppreference.com where needed.

Comment: There already exists a std::rotate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initializing r with a.size() copies of 0 at the start of your code:

```
vector<int> r(a.size());
```

At this point, the vector `r` contains values `0 0 0 0 0` (as many zeroes as there are elements in `a`).

Then, you push values onto the back of this vector of zeroes. At each step of your loops:

```
0 0 0 0 0 5
0 0 0 0 0 5 1
0 0 0 0 0 5 1 2
0 0 0 0 0 5 1 2 3
0 0 0 0 0 5 1 2 3 4
```

Instead, initialize with an empty vector:

```
vector<int> r;
```

Answer (score 1):

The local variable of `vector<int> r(a.size())` uses a vector's constructor overload that accepts `(size_type count)` argument and is initialized (or rather zeroed out) to contain `a.size()` number of `0`s. For clarification check out the [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) constructor overload no. 3:

> The overload (3) zeroes out elements of non-class types such as int

Use a default constructor to create an empty container instead:

```
std::vector<int> r;
```

or:

```
std::vector<int> r{};
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> vector<int> r(a.size());
> ```

With this line, you create a vector of initial size `a.size()`; the initial elements in the vector are set to 0.

Probably your `a` vector has size 5, so this is where the five zeros in your output come from:

```
0 0 0 0 0
```

Then, you invoke the `push_back()` method on `r`, and this appends other elements at the end of the `r` vector.

To get a better help, please clarify your goal.